# Mule/Groovy - List of Canonicals split to 3 more lists

Tags: java, groovy, mule, dataweave

I have a list of canonical objects

```
[{code=SW0606,date=20150101},{code=SW0606,date=20150107},{code=YL2424,date=20150105},{code=YL2424,date=20150103},{code=OP7676,date=20150102},{code=OP7676,date=20160102}]
```

I want to achieve three lists based on value code
eg.

```
List1=[{code=SW0606,date=20150101},{code=SW0606,date=20150107}]
List2=[{code=YL2424,date=20150105},{code=YL2424,date=20150103}]
List3=[{code=OP7676,date=20150102},{code=OP7676,date=20160102}]
```

and then push these list to one bigger list

```
ListofLists= List1,List2,List3
```

What is a simplest way to do that?

Comment: You want to split in three equal parts?  and then add them back together?  What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
canonicalObjectsList.groupBy({obj -> obj.code}).values().toList()
```

Comment: Multiple Markers at this line, seems like it is a problem in this code

Comment: I've tried in groovy console: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5120540071165952
It works as expected.

Comment: Thank you, it's really working it was my another exception in script !